# Lots of Akka Threads in Tomcat

Tags: scala, tomcat, akka, spray

I'm hosting my Scala (2.11) WAR inside Tomcat 8 and am using `akka` 2.3.+ and `spray-client` 1.3.3. I am using Akka for only one actor and am dispatching a call to it once when Tomcat starts. It can also be called manually.

```
class RefreshDataActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case _ =>
            implicit val timeout: Timeout = someTimeout
            implicit val ec = this.context.dispatcher

            val pipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[Data]

            pipeline(Get(fileUrl))
                .onComplete {
                    case Success(data) =>
                        // Do stuff with the data
                    case Failure(ex) =>
                        this.log.error("Unable to find the latest version of the data!", ex)
                }
    }
}
```

Whenever any call comes into Tomcat, I see a spike in the number of live threads it hosts.

[image: VisualVM screencap]

The arrows indicate when calls were made to the server. Also note that CPU slowly rises too and at some point the machine ends up working very hard over what seems to be nothing (the machine in the screencap has 8 cores).

I started debugging the issue by connecting VisualVM to one of the machines that is affected by this. The threads that remain alive are named `default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-X` (where `X` is usually any number between 2 and 7), all of which are WAITING and `default-scheduler-1` (TIMED_WAITING). **There are HUNDREDS of them.** There's also a single `default-akka.io.pinned-dispatcher-5` (RUNNABLE).

I'm assuming this has something to do with how Akka works, but don't understand why this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue. I was calling `ActorSystem()` more than once, which created a new actor system, rather than reuse the already created one. This caused more and more systems to be created and, for some reason, not to be removed.

Comment: Actor system does not die until you explicitly terminate it.